# Screens go black when connecting second screen

Tags: multiple-monitors, gpu-driver

I recently installed Ubuntu GNOME on my laptop to try to replace Windows, but one thing does not seem to work anymore (I'm quite sure it worked initially): I can't use my laptop as soon as I connect my TV (HDMI), as the TV remains black and the laptop display goes black (but seems to flicker*). I think it happend first after I installed nVidia driver 340 (it was the latest driver in the additional drivers tool), but even switching back to the default xorg (?) driver does not help (or do I need to restart first?). Anyway, I installed the hoepfully really latest nVidia driver 352 (from ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa -y), but still nothing has changed. It really keeps me from replacing Windows with Linux.

The laptop is equipped with an GTX 660M and an Intel i5, which has some kind of integrated GPU. But still, I'm quite sure that - initially - it worked, so it doesn't look like the Intel GPU is the main problem.

- What I mean with flicker is: it seems to go from off to on (black) and back, and you can hear a silent *click* every time it switches (which happens ~ 1/s)

Comment: - When I connect second screen I use [ARandR Screen Layout](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/arandr-a-simple-visual-front-end-for-xrandr.html)
- What's your kernel version? Try to [update to the latest kernel](http://askubuntu.com/a/485971/330104).